# API DomPDF para geração de PDF em PHP

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Utilizo o software laragon que já vem com laravel e composer integrado ao projeto, executei a linha:

Nota: não me preucupei com boas praticas ainda, quero fazer ele funcionar primeiro

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

Para instalar a api de geração de PDF.
Adicionei as seguintes linhas no arquivo da pasta /config app.php

Em providers

```
Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
```

Em aliases

```
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
```

Importei na classe onde está o método de geração do pdf

```
use PDF;
```

No código ja utilizei de diversas formas e nenhuma funcionou:

```
    $clientes = Cliente::all();
    $view = view('Pdf.PdfClientesReport2', compact('clientes'));
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');      
    $pdf->loadHTML($view);
    //Aqui ele conseguir ver pelo dd() que ele pega dados do pdf mas nao 
    consigo imprimir
    //dd($pdf);   
    $pdf->download('clientes');
```

Dessa forma também com uma function dentro do método de geração:

```
function geraTeste($clientes){

        $code = "<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>

            <title>Document</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>nome</td>
                    <td>CPF/CNPJ</td>
                    <td>IE</td>
                </tr>";

        foreach ($clientes as $c){
            $code += "<tr>";
            $code += "<td>'.$c->name.'</td>";
            $code += "<td>'.$c->cpf_cnpj.'</td>";
            $code += "<td>'.$c->inscricao_est.'</td>";
            $code += "</tr>";

        }
        $code += "</table>";
        $code += "</body>
        </html>";

        return $code;
    }

    $clientes = Cliente::all();
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML(geraTeste($clientes));
    return $pdf->stream();
```

Dessa forma também:

```
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('Pdf.PdfClientesReport2', compact('clientes'));
    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Dessa também:

```
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('Pdf.PdfClientesReport2', $clientes);
    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

**Consegui dessa forma agora a pouco, más eu queria poder abrir no proprio navegador de tiver como.**

```
$pdf  =  \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $view =  View::make('Pdf.PdfClientesReport2', compact('clientes'))->render();
    $pdf->loadHTML($view);
    $pdf->stream();
    //return $pdf->stream('invoice');
    return $pdf->download('profile.pdf');
```

Se alguém puder ajudar, aceito sujestões..

Comment: Galera boa tarde
no meu caso, estou usando angular4 no front e laravel no backend, quando consulto a api laravel pelo postman, consigo fazer o download do PDF, quando faço a requisição HTTP no angular o mesmo me retorna positivo mais a janela de download não abre para baixar o arquivo pode me ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Qunado vc utilizou o `return $pdf->stream();` não passou o nome do arquivo a ser montado.

```
return $pdf->stream('profile.pdf');
```

Assim deve funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um PDF viewer em Javascript para receber o streaming, sugiro o Mozilla PDF.js:

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/